# Flick Video Player aspect ratio or strech/fit the video itself in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I am using *flick_video_player* plugin from here https://pub.dev/packages/flick_video_player. I am displaying a video from *Firestorage*. It is working, but I can not change the aspect ratio. Like you can see below, I want to fit the container, because now it's cropped from the original one.
I tried to use *flickVideoWithControls: const FlickVideoWithControls(videoFit: BoxFit.cover,)*, but without success.

```
  class SessionSubchapterClass extends StatefulWidget {
      const SessionSubchapterClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      State<SessionSubchapterClass> createState() => _SessionSubchapterClassState();
    }
    class _SessionSubchapterClassState extends State<SessionSubchapterClass>  with TickerProviderStateMixin{
      bool isLoading = false;
    
      late FlickManager flickManager;
    double getScale() {
    double videoRatio = flickManager.flickVideoManager!.videoPlayerValue!.aspectRatio;

    if (videoRatio < videoContainerRatio) {
      ///for tall videos, we just return the inverse of the controller aspect ratio
      return videoContainerRatio / videoRatio;
    } else {
      ///for wide videos, divide the video AR by the fixed container AR
      ///so that the video does not over scale

      return videoRatio / videoContainerRatio;
    }
  }
      @override
      initState() {
        super.initState();
        flickManager = FlickManager(
          videoPlayerController:
          VideoPlayerController.network(widget.sessionSubchapter.video!),
        );
      }
      @override
      void dispose() {
        flickManager.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        scale = getScale();
        return isLoading ? const LoadingSpinner() : Sizer(
            builder: (ctx, orientation, deviceType)
            {
              return Scaffold(
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                appBar: AppBar(
                  toolbarHeight: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.mobile ? 8.h : 9.h,
                  centerTitle: true,
                  leading: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.mobile ?  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.w, 1.h, 0, 1.h) : EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.w, 1.h, 0, 1.h),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style:
                        ButtonStyle(
                            padding: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.mobile ? MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.w, 1.h, 2.w, 1.h)) : MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.w, 1.h, 2.w, 1.h)),
                            elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                0), //Defines Elevation
                            shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                .all(Colors.white),
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                .all(const Color(0xffE4BCB4)),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                      .circular(12.0),
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.close, color: const Color(0xff393432), size: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.mobile ? 25 : 35,),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  elevation: 0,
                  titleSpacing: 0,
                  actions: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 1.h, 3.w, 1.h),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style:
                        ButtonStyle(
                            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.w, 1.h, 2.w, 1.h)),
                            elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                0), //Defines Elevation
                            shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                .all(Colors.white),
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                .all(const Color(0xffE4BCB4)),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                      .circular(12.0),
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                          onPressed: (){
                            },
                          child: Text('MARK DONE',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: const Color(0xff393432),
                              fontSize: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.mobile ? 15 : 25,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xff393432),
                ),
                body: SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: FlickVideoPlayer(
                            flickManager: flickManager,
                          flickVideoWithControls: const FlickVideoWithControls(videoFit: BoxFit.cover,),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 5,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20))
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              TabBar(
                                controller: _tabController,
                                indicatorColor: const Color(0xffE4BCB4),
                                indicatorWeight: 4,
                                tabs: [
                                  Container(
                                    margin: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.mobile ? const EdgeInsets.all(0) : const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 13, 0, 13),
                                    child: Tab(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Class",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.mobile ? 15 : 25,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.mobile ? const EdgeInsets.all(0) : const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 13, 0, 13),
                                    child: Tab(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Work",
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize:SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.mobile ? 15 : 25,),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: TabBarView(
                                    controller: _tabController,
                                    children:[
                                      Container(
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 20, 15, 0),
                                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                            child: Column(
                                              children: [
                                                Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    SizedBox(
                                                      width: 50.w,
                                                      child: Column(
                                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text(
                                                            widget.titleOfChapter,
                                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,
                                                              fontSize: SizerUtil.deviceType ==
                                                                  DeviceType.mobile ? 14 : 23,),
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    SizedBox(
                                                      width: 40.w,
                                                      child: Column(
                                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text("Activity ${widget.sessionSubchapter.order.toString()}/${widget.noOfActivities}", style:
                                                            TextStyle(
                                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                                              fontSize: SizerUtil.deviceType ==
                                                                  DeviceType.mobile ? 14 : 23,
                                                            ),)
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                const SizedBox(height: 15),
                                                Row(children: [
                                                  Flexible(
                                                    child: Text(widget.sessionSubchapter.title!, style:
                                                    TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      fontSize: SizerUtil.deviceType ==
                                                          DeviceType.mobile ? 20 : 30,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    ),),
                                                  )
                                                ],),
                                                const SizedBox(height: 15),
                                                Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Flexible(
                                                      child: Text(widget.sessionSubchapter.description!, style:
                                                      TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                        fontSize: SizerUtil.deviceType ==
                                                            DeviceType.mobile ? 17 : 27,
                                                      ),),
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SingleChildScrollView(
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              widget.sessionSubchapter.cleanSheet!="" ?
                                              Container(
                                                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 20, 15, 0),
                                                  width: 80.w,
                                                  height: 50.h,
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1), // Border width
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                                                      size: const Size.fromRadius(48), // Image radius
                                                      child: Image.network(widget.sessionSubchapter.cleanSheet!, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                              ) :
                                              Container(
                                                width: 100.w,
                                                height: 14.h,
                                                color: const Color(0xffF3F2F2),
                                                child: InkWell(
                                                  onTap: () async {
                                                    try {
                                                      log(widget.sessionSubchapter.cleanSheetPdf!);
                                                      setState(() {
                                                      });
                                                    }
                                                    catch(e) {
                                                      log(e.toString());
                                                    }
                                                  },
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.w, 3.5.h, 5.w, 3.5.h),
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                                                    ),
                                                    child:
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Flexible(
                                                          child: Container(
                                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 0),
                                                            child: Text("Activity Worksheet: Design Your Set", style:
                                                            TextStyle(
                                                              color: Colors.black,
                                                              fontSize: SizerUtil.deviceType ==
                                                                  DeviceType.mobile ? 16 : 26,
                                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                            ),),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Container(
                                                          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 0),
                                                          child: Icon(Icons.insert_drive_file_outlined, size: SizerUtil.deviceType ==
                                                              DeviceType.mobile ? 24 : 34,color: Colors.grey,),
                                                        )
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          )),
                                    ]
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
        );
      }
    }
```

How it is:
[image]

How I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by using *Chewie* plugin from here https://pub.dev/packages/chewie.

```
 videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        widget.sessionSubchapter.video!);

    videoPlayerController.initialize();

    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
    ...
    Expanded(
     flex: 3,
     child: Chewie(
     controller: chewieController,
     ),
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try to adjust this property **videoFit: BoxFit.fitHeight**

```
child: FlickVideoPlayer(
              flickVideoWithControls: FlickVideoWithControls(
                videoFit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                controls: FlickPortraitControls(
                  progressBarSettings:
                      FlickProgressBarSettings(playedColor: Colors.green),
                ),
              ),
              flickManager: flickManager,
            ),
```